# Private repository - update so new rpms can be pulled immediately

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I setup a private repository (local mount for now) and built custom rpms.  The idea is to build the rpm, add it to the repo, and trigger a `yum update mypackage` to several servers.

The problem I'm having is that the newer version of the rpm does not show up... and the old version of the rpm still does, even after I delete it from the repo.

I've tried `yum update` and `yum clean all` but it does not get the latest data in my local repo.

When I uninstall the package, and re-install it, it tries to install the old rpm that is no longer present, and fails.

What is the process to update the repo data so I can run updates immediately?

** update **

As I was writing this, I thought to try `createrepo .` after I updated the rpms.  This allowed me to install the latest version.

Is this what I should run after updating the files?

Comment: Yes, each time you modify the set of RPMs in a repository, `createrepo .` is mandatory. The `yum` command relies on metadata files created by this command to operate correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fge's comment is correct. Every time you add a new rpm to a repository you must run createrepo. Otherwise the repo metadata doesn't get updated so it still sees the previous RPM as the latest version.

Edit: The docs that I linked to that explained the same steps as the answer below by Steve Goodman were removed for some reason, check out that answer instead (https://stackoverflow.com/a/18604484/1263015)

Answer (score 8):

The fastest way to rebuild your repository metadata is to use the --update flag for createrepo:

```
createrepo --update -v /path/to/repo
```

This will only process RPMs added to your repo since the last time createrepo was run.

Answer (score 0):

I also found that I needed to modify my yum.repo.d/internal.repo file to include a metadata_expire line that expires the metadata sooner than usual.

```
[internal]
metadata_expire=1h
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out OpenRepo: https://github.com/openkilt/openrepo

This is an open source package hosting server that can make packages available for both Debian (APT) and Red Hat (RPM) files.

When you push a package to a repo, it handles the push/update of the repo metadata files